# Jquery, Javascript and Observer Pattern

Tags: jquery

Im tring to use the observer pattern in javascript with JQuery, but the trigger and bind doesnt work. How may i do it to get the "alert('notify binded');" run? thanks ;)

```
(function($){
    var NoteApp = function(){
        var self = this;
        this.notifications = [];
        this.EVENT = {
                NOTIFY: 'notify'
        };
        this.button = {
                ask_number: $('#ask-number'),
                ask_email: $('#ask-mail'),
                ask_out: $('#ask-out')
        };

        var Button = function(){

        };


        var Data = function(app){

            $(app.notifications).bind(app.EVENT.NOTIFY, function(){
                alert('notify binded');
            });

        }(this);


        var UI = function(app){

            app.button.ask_number.bind(app.EVENT.NOTIFY, function(){
                alert('notify 2');
            });

            app.button.ask_number.click(function(){
                //alert(app.EVENT.NOTIFY);
                $(app.notifications).trigger(app.EVENT.NOTIFY);
                return false;
            })


        }(this);
    }

    NoteApp = new NoteApp();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few remarks about your code:

1. The `notifications` array is always empty - `[]`. There's nothing in your code which puts elements inside it so the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function binds to nothing.
2. `NoteApp = new NoteApp();` should be called when the DOM is ready or the `ask_number`, `ask_email` and `ask_out` elements might not yet be initialized.

Comment: already solved. The problem wa with binds and triggers, because they didnt work well, so i made a new class.